# NullPointerException at BoringLayout.isBoring is anything but boring

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

A stack trace below
Usually doesn't happen, but happens here and there to some users.

On Android 2.3.3 the exception happens on BoringLayout.isBoring:240
On Android 4.1.2 the same, line 260

Any help would be appreciated. :-)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:260)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6322)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1223)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1853)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1778)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1614)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your code relevant parts

Comment: "Usually doesn't happen, but happens here and there to some users." Any chance you're updating the UI from a background thread?

Comment: Also, what Android version does this happen on? Looking at `master` of the framework, you probably set your TextView's text to be `null`.

Comment: @Raghunandan - if I knew where in my code to look I would be able to find the bug myself

Comment: @Dan Breslau quite possible, although this is not the exception I would expect to see in that case.

Comment: @Delyan This is a nice hint, this sounds the most likely. Any way I could narrow it down, besides searching all my textviews? any trick you can think of to give me better direction?

Comment: @JRun without code it would be a guess or assumption. i don't think i can help further. good luck

Comment: yes it will bore you even ur q bored me too

Comment: Well, the exact line where the exception is thrown is detailed in the logcat.  You could start by posting the `isBoring` method.

Comment: The isBoring method is part of the framework. The meaning of that particular line depends on the Android version. In the current state of the framework, it means that the text CharSequence is null.

Comment: @Deylan.  Huh!  Thank you.  I didn't know about that class, but reading the docs, I'm not surprised!  A checked out the source, and yes, it seems that charSequence == null is the likely cause.

Comment: @Delyan Thanks. I guess there's no way for me to narrow this down, so I have to look at all the places where I set the textView... I'll take a hack at it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, you know it's a TextView in a LinearLayout in a LinearLayout in a LinearLayout in a ListView in a RelativeLayout in a FrameLayout in a ViewPager. Surely, that must narrow it down! :)

Comment: @Delyan Ha. I have managed to get two instances of the exception where I know the Android version. Android 2.3.3 - BoringLayout:isBoring:240, and Android 4.1.2, line 260.

Comment: Both of those are the same line, which imply that the `mTransformed` `CharSequence` being passed to `isBoring` is `null`. However, looking at the `TextView` source, that should be impossible unless you have a text transformation which somehow returns the transformed text as `null`. This is as much as I can help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JRun "quite possible, although this is not the exception I would expect to see in that case." In my experience, trying to predict in advance what kinds of errors one can get from improper use of threads is a poor use of time. I urge you to eliminate whatever UI updates you're making in background threads; put them on the main thread where they belong. If that doesn't fix this problem, it will assuredly fix others.

Comment: @Deylan thanks, now I know what piece of the code is likely the cause. I have 2 classes that override TextView. I added the code for my most likely suspect

Answer (score 19):

Ok found it.
I'm not deleting the question because maybe it would help someone some day.

So my mistake was:
I have extended TextView to create a class that manipulates the text, and look depending on the value set.

My error was that in some cases I chose not to set the text, and simply called 'return'. In those cases the 'text' was null, which caused the above NPE.

Lesson: If you override setText, a value MUST be set when it is called.

This is one of those points in time I remember 'design by contract', preconditions, invariants etc. This could have been helpful here.

To all those that tried to help, you have my thanks. 
@Deylan - special thanks, you were the one that gave me the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: today it has helped me. So thank you for directing me the same.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.